# How do i change form's action property when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, forms, action

I would like to change the form's action property when a button is clicked

I have two buttons in a form and when each button is clicked each should post data to own url.

html:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="button" value="Edit Selected..." />
<input type="button" value="Delete Selected..." />
...
</form>
```

Comment: You'd be better off making those buttons into submits, giving them a name, then determining which one was clicked on the server.

Comment: Why don't you use `if/else` to see that which value is received and process according to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GOD it was so similar to native javascript that i missed it...

i am not sure its plane javascript or with jquery but i got the following code exactly as i needed and worked fine:

```
        $('#cmdDeleteButton').click(function(){
            this.form.action = "http://newurl.com";
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

> using jQuery

```
<form method="post" id="form1">
<input type="button"  data-url="action2"  value="Edit Selected..." />
<input type="button" data-url="action1" value="Delete Selected..." />
...
</form>
```

script:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[type*="button"]').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('data-url');


     $('#form1').attr('action',url);   

    });

});
```

Comment: can we directly refer the form without using the #form1 just like by parent or form

Comment: yeah sure, you can use $('form')

Comment: no it won't.... to select particular form you need to correct selector here you can learn about selectors http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html in other way use id for form

Comment: can't we just grab the form from the button inside it?

Comment: modify that selector $('#form1 input[type*="button"]')  here is working demo http://jsfiddle.net/HhMbV/

Comment: @KoolKabin: $(this).closest('form') will give you the correct form around the clicked button. **[closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** is one of my favorite traversal methods :-) And please, don't curse on stackoverflow or Jesus.